# How to configure capybara not to clear cookies and reset session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, automated-tests, capybara

Between running one test scenario and another, the default Capybara setting opens the blank page and clears cookies from the previous scenario, eliminating the session that was recorded in the first scenario.

How to configure Capybara not to clear cookies of a session between one scenario and another?

These are the settings I currently have

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
    config.default_max_wait_time = 10
    config.app_host = 'https://website.com'    
end
```

Comment: You don't want to do this. Tests are self-contained, sharing state from one test to the next is a huge problem, and everything about Rails testing framework is meant to prevent this.

Comment: Inside a feature I have scenarios.
The first test scenario is a successful login.
The second scenario is to access the reporting screen.
When successfully executing the first scenario, in the second scenario execution it is redirected to login screen, is losing session.
I understand that by default you should keep the session logged in to run all test scenarios of the same feature.
I don't know why you are dropping the session.

Comment: Tests shouldn't polute other tests, it's ok session is not mantained, you can relogin on your new test or (better) mock the logged user (if you use devise you have some helpers to bypass the login process https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers)